Cómo liberar espacio de almacenamiento en proxmox?
tengo el inconveniente de que borre unas máquinas virtuales en Proxmox, pero a pesar de eso, no aumenta el espacio disponible, siempre me aparece como que está reservado.
Que puedo hacer? Perdón que no de mucho detalle, pero creo que no hay mucho que explicar.
Gracias de antemano
